# RxJava Android zip many requests with different types

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, reactivex

I have a bit "estetic" problem with Observable.zip function. You use it like this:

```
Observerbale.zip(
    reqA, reqB, reqC,
    (a, b, c) -> {/*deal with them*/});
```

The amount of requests equals amount of params in "deal-with-it" function. Now, if you have more requests, like 6, you'll end up with function, that takes 6 arguments (let assume, that all of them have different types). It just doesn't feel clean. Is there a way to wrap them in one class, as e.g. attributes?

My real-life problem right now is, that I use zip, to load setup data:

```
Observable.zip(
    loadAPIMenus(),                        //1.
    databaseService.readFavorites(),       //2.
    (menuResponse, favorites) -> loadFavorites(menuResponse, favorites)) //3.
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        menus -> menuSubscriber.onNext(menus), //4.
        error -> menuSubscriber.onError(error));
```

> 1. loads items for list view from rest api
> 2. loads ids of those items, which are stored as favorite in db
> 3. merges both lists, so items, which are favorite, are have isFavorite >set to true
> 4. Updates list view

It's not that bad now. But I'ld like to add 2-3 requests for other data end function at #3 will grow to 4-line mammoth with too many function params.

I figured, that I can use Observable.zip nested one in another, but may be dangerous. Is there any more ellegant way to wrap those params?

I'ld be glad to see your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the docs for `Observable::zip()`, it states:

> "You can provide the Observables to be zipped together to zip either as between two and nine individual parameters, **or as a single parameter: either an Iterable of Observables or an Observable that emits Observables (as in the illustration above).**"

That opens the door to using some form of `Iterable<Observable<T>>`, or `Observable<Observable<T>>` instead of the overloads that take anywhere between 2-9 `Observable`s that you're using now.

With this approach, the last parameter to `zip` also now becomes `FuncN`, which is called with an argument list `Object... args` as its parameter, which you can treat like an array.

If you use the `Observable::zip(Iterable, FuncN)` approach, you could:

```
List<Observable<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(req1);
list.add(req2);

Observable.zip(list, new FuncN<???>() {
    @Override
    public ??? call(Object... args) {
        return ???;
    }
);
```

I wouldn't bother with the `Observable<Observable<T>>` in your case since that requires you to create a list or array of observable to pass to `Observable::from()` in the first place, although there might be a better way to do that.

Comment: Thanks drhr! It's way better, than making function with up to nine parameters!